# WKWebView not changing contentSize after modify images sizes in javascript

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I use WKWebView with loadHTMLString and basicURL.
I observe changes of "scrollView.contentSize" path and execute next code owhen content size changing:

```
if (textWebViewHeightConstraint.constant != textWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height) {
   CGFloat newSize = textWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
   if (!self.currentPromo.text || self.currentPromo.text.length == 0) {
       newSize = 0.0;
   }
   [UIView animateWithDuration:kDefaultAnimationDuration animations:^{
       textWebViewHeightConstraint.constant = newSize;
       [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
   }];
}
```

It work correct.
But my html string sometimes containt big images with static width and height.

I modify images sizes in didFinishNavigation method:

```
[webView evaluateJavaScript:@"var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');"
 "for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {"
    "images[i].style.height = \"auto\";"
    "images[i].style.maxWidth = window.innerWidth - kDefaultMargin * 2;"
 "}" completionHandler:nil];
```

After executing this JS code, content height changed, but WKWebView not detecting this, and not change content size. In result I have a big free space in WKWebView after end of content.

How I can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, why are you changing the scrollView's contentSize to begin with?  The WKWebView will handle this for you

Comment: I dont change scrollView's contentSize manually, I read changes in scrollView's contentSize via observer and update WKWebView height constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix it!
I dont know, why WKWebView content size not resizing automatically, but we can help him do it.

If you have a same problem as mine, you should:

Delcare BOOL property

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL isWebViewReloaded;
```

and set to NO value in your update view content method

```
self.isWebViewReloaded = NO;
NSString *wrappedText = [self.currentPromo wrappedTextForWebViewForWith:self.textWebView.bounds.size.width andText:nil];
[self.textWebView loadHTMLString:wrappedText baseURL:[ApiClient shared].baseUrl];
```

My wrapped method add html and body tags to html string

```
-(NSString *)wrappedTextForWebViewForWith:(CGFloat)width andText:(NSString *)text {
    if (!text) {
        text = self.text;
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"<html>"
                "<head>"
                    "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\" />"
                "</head>"
                "<body style=\"max-width:%fpx\">"
                    "%@"
                "</body>"
            "</html>", width, text];
}
```

In didStartProvisionalNavigation delegate methood your should manually set content size to zero. **It is very important, without its WKWebView will be no resize!**

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didStartProvisionalNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation {
    webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeZero;
}
```

In didFinishNavigation delegate method your should modify your already loaded document and reload WKWebView with modified html

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation {
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:self.modifyImagesJS completionHandler:^(id _Nullable obj, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         if (!self.isWebViewReloaded) {
             //it is very big hack! See my question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761656/wkwebview-not-changing-contentsize-after-modify-images-sizes-in-javascript
             [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.body.innerHTML" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable str, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                 self.isWebViewReloaded = YES;
                 NSString *wrappedHTML = [self.currentPromo wrappedTextForWebViewForWith:self.textWebView.bounds.size.width andText:str];
                 [self.textWebView loadHTMLString:wrappedHTML baseURL:[ApiClient shared].baseUrl];
             }];
         }
     }];
}
```

My isWebViewReloaded script:

```
self.modifyImagesJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""
                       "var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');"
                       "for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {"
                            "images[i].removeAttribute(\"height\");"
                            "images[i].style.height = \"auto\";"
                            "images[i].style.maxWidth = window.innerWidth - %f * 2;" //  %f * 2 - сompensate left and right margins
                       "}", kDefaultSmallBlocksMargins];
```

and finally I use KVO for detect of webview content size changes and modify webview height constraint

```
FBKVOController *kvo = self.KVOController;
[kvo observe:self.textWebView
     keyPath:@"scrollView.contentSize"
     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
       block:^(id _Nullable observer, WKWebView * _Nonnull webView, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull change) {
           if (webView.constraints.firstObject.constant != webView.scrollView.contentSize.height) {
               NSLog(@"new size is %f", webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
               CGFloat newSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
               if (!_self.currentPromo.text || _self.currentPromo.text.length == 0) {
                   newSize = 0.0;
               }
               [UIView animateWithDuration:kDefaultAnimationDuration animations:^{
                   webView.constraints.firstObject.constant = newSize;
                   [_self.view layoutIfNeeded];
               }];
           }
       }];
```

**BINGO!!!**

Original html string:

```
... <img width="600" src="/upload/someName.png" height="2001">...
```

Html string after modify

```
...  <img width="600" src="/upload/someName.png" style="height: auto; max-width: 284px;"> ...
```

Changes of content size

```
...[26964:10644727] new size is 2297.000000
...[26964:10644727] new size is 0.000000
...[26964:10644727] new size is 1243.000000
```

Comment: I foggot a small, but very important instruction.
In viewDidLoad method your should add a height constraint.
via Masonry example:


`[self.newsContentWebView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {


    make.height.mas_equalTo(@0);


}];`